# I can't import Spotify classes

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I can't import Spotify classes even though I added their dependencies in gradle.

`import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.AuthorizationResponse import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.SpotifyConstants import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.SpotifyAuthorization`

My gradle dependences `dependencies {

```
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation ("com.spotify.android:auth:1.1.0")
implementation ("com.spotify.android:app-remote:0.7.0")
implementation ("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
```

}`

tank you for help

I tried solutions on the API page, but due to my lack of experience, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This version is very [outdated](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify.android/auth/1.1.0) and isn't on Maven Central (that's why it hasn't been resolved without additional setup while syncing project with gradle), please try changing the `auth` dependency to the newest:

```
implementation("com.spotify.android:auth:2.1.0")
```

As for the `app-remote`, I couldn't find it published as a maven repo, only as an aar [here](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/releases/tag/v0.8.0-appremote_v2.1.0-auth)